# How to use "formatMessage" module with i18n model and parameters in XML views

Tags: sapui5

In the UI5 Demo Kit, [Walkthrough step 8](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/df86bfbeab0645e5b764ffa488ed57dc) (still) mentions the following:

> To be on the safe side, we would have to use a similar mechanism as in the controller to use a string from the resource bundle and replace parts of it. This can be done with the `jQuery.sap.formatMessage` formatter.

It can be used for translatable texts with placeholders in XML views e.g.:

```xml
<Title text="{
  parts: [
    'i18n>overflowToolbarTitle',
    'appView>/listItemCount'
  ],
  formatter: 'jQuery.sap.formatMessage'
}" />
```

However, `jQuery.sap.formatMessage` **is depreciated** since 1.58, and if I use instead the suggested alternative `sap.base.strings.formatMessage`, the following error is thrown:

> formatter function sap.base.strings.formatMessage not found!

How can the new `formatMessage` module be used in XML?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## UI5 1.69+

With `commit:2dab48e`, it is now possible to [*require modules declaratively in XML views*](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/b11d853a8e784db6b2d210ef57b0f7d7):

```xml
<Title xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
  core:require="{ formatMessage: 'sap/base/strings/formatMessage' }"
  text="{
    parts: [
      'i18n>overflowToolbarTitle',
      'appView>/listItemCount'
    ],
    formatter: 'formatMessage'
  }"
/>
```

With this, we can avoid having dependency to an intermediate Controller and make use of the new module independently.

---

## UI5 1.68 and below (previous answer)

UI5 currently doesn't allow fetching and assigning a module to the `formatter`.<sup>1</sup> Furthermore, the new function module is never exported with the name `sap.base.strings.formatMessage`.[<sup>src</sup>](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/base/strings/formatMessage.js)

One of the alternative approaches would be to point to the method assigned in the controller whereas that method points to the required `formatMessage` module.

```xml
<Title text="{
  parts: [
    'i18n>overflowToolbarTitle',
    'appView>/listItemCount'
  ],
  formatter: '.formatMessage'
}"/>
```

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
  "sap/base/strings/formatMessage",
  // ...
], function(Controller, formatMessage/*, ...*/) {
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("...", {
    formatMessage: formatMessage,
    // ...
  });
})
```

I could imagine that UI5 supports fetching and assigning modules within binding definition in later versions, but at the time of writing it's not possible.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Related enhancement request: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2475</sup>

Comment: One can enhance this a bit further, by using `parts: [{path: '...'}, {value: 'someStaticValue'}]` in case a static parameter has to be passed to the i18n model.

Comment: @fmi21 Yes, static binding is possible since UI5 1.61: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53609552/5846045

Comment: I've also noticed you're using some form of 'shorthand' syntax in the 'parts' part, where you can omit the token 'path' and directly specify it as a string and not an object array instead. Do you have any references for this as well?

Comment: @fmi21 Using strings only in `parts` is allowed according to https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/a2fe8e763014477e87990ff50657a0d0

Comment: @fmi21 The type information of `parts` is now fixed in the API reference accroding to the commit from today: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/2eeaf175f4f4bc94b0dc743dc525e7d840194b08

Comment: Hi! Am I missing some important part here? I have defined `core:require` in the `View` definition, and then in Text control I have the same  - one part with i18n text with placeholder and second part with that value for placeholder. Yet when I run the app - it is just empty, also no errors. I'm on 1.99. The expected outcome is "User: {0}"

Comment: Hi @Shanir , could you share an [MCVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example)? Preferably via Plunker or in a separate question..

Comment: Why can we use `formatter: 'sap.ui.require.toUrl'`, but not `formatter: 'sap.base.strings.formatMessage'`? :-)

Comment: @Pieter The "Previous Answer" explains the reason "[...] the new function module is never exported with the name `sap.base.strings.formatMessage`". See also https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2475