# Getting the resource bundle from the controller's owner components returns (fulfilled) promise

Tags: sapui5

Following [this example,](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/0f8626ed7b7542ffaa44601828db20de.html) in SAP UI5 (I'm using 1.108 atm), the call to `this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle()` returns a fulfilled promise instead of the resource bundle object.

Since what version or via what setting is this behaviour changed?

To cope with this, I'm using await in my formatter function:

```js
sap.ui.define([], function () {
  'use strict'

  return {
    formatText: async function () {
      var oRB = await this.getOwnerComponent()
          .getModel('i18n')
          .getResourceBundle()
      return oRB.getText('hi')
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether `sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel#getResourceBundle` returns a promise or the actual resource bundle depends on whether the respective `ResourceModel` is supposed to load the `*.properties` files asynchronously or not.

If e.g. the constructor setting of the `ResourceModel` has `async: true`, the API `getResourceBundle` returns a promise. Take a look at your `ResourceModel` settings in the `manifest.json` section `/sap.ui5/models/i18n/settings`. There, you must have `"async": true`.

---

- API reference: [`sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel)
- Q&A: [How to use `formatMessage` module with i18n model and parameters in XML views?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55587775/5846045)